# How to know if a PHP variable is being retrieved by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm having some trouble in JS function for combobox. It functions well if there is a PHP variable being passed, but if there's nothing, the whole block of code doesn't work. I've tried using `if(typeof(<?php echo json_encode($information['day']) ?>)!='undefined')` but it still doesn't work. Is there another way on how to determine if the PHP variable is set or passed?

Comment: What about the `isset` function? http://www.php.net/isset

Comment: `typeof(null) != 'undefined` as well.

Comment: Yes, the isset function worked. I just didn't know that it can be applied to JS :) Thanks sirs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more ways to do this than I can think of. Here is one.

```
 <script>
    <?php if( isset($information) && isset($information['day']) ) { ?>
      var myJson = <?php echo json_encode($information); ?>;
    <?php } else { ?>
      var myJson = null;
    <?php } ?>

    if(myJson != null) {

    // do something
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It worked! I didn't know that I can use a PHP if else in JS. hahaha. Thank you very much for your answer, you saved my life :D

Answer (score 0):

Change this line of code

```
if(typeof(<?php echo json_encode($information['day']) ?>)!='undefined')
```

to this

```
if(typeof("<?php echo json_encode($information['day']); ?>") != 'undefined')
```

Comment: I tried this code as well, but it didn't work. Anyway, thank you for answering :)

Comment: Can you provide us more details about this? plus have you checked $information['day'] if it is defined and has value?

Comment: Originally, I used this code:
`if(<?php echo json_encode($information['day']) ?> != "00"){
  d = <?php echo json_encode($information['day']); ?>;
 }`

I used the != "00" so that I won't have to store the blank day value to the variable anymore. (anyway, the function is for cascading dropdown for date, so I can still get the 2014-05-00 value if ever)
Then I used this:
`<?php if(isset($information['day'])&&($information['day']!="00")){ ?>
  d = <?php echo json_encode($information['day']); ?>;
 <?php } ?>`

It worked out fine since the script detects the $information['day'] now.